# Mysql error on debian server

Tags: sql, mysql, debian

Hi i have a debian server.

Today my site was showing Error establishing a database connection.

When i tried to restart mysql i am getting this error:

**ERROR: The partition with is too full! failed!**

I have run apt-get clean command also but still i am getting this error.

Please help

Comment: Check 'df' to see if you're out of space. Other than that, this belongs on Serverfault or Superuser.

Comment: I think you're out of diskspace - check with df.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying  i am getting this on running df:

Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              9805144   9308424         0 100% /
tmpfs                   131156         0    131156   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                    131156        20    131136   1% /dev
tmpfs                   131156         0    131156   0% /dev/shm
none                    131156         0    131156   0% /dev/shm
overflow                  1024         0      1024   0% /tmp

What does this indicate & is there any temporary solution because this is very critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are out of disk space.  Have you checked?  This will tell you how full your mounts are:

```
df
```

---

I've tried to put your comment into the below block.  It looked to me like your drive is full.  Use% = 100% is bad.

```
Filesystem      1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on 
/dev/sda1         9805144 9308424         0 100% 
/tmpfs             131156       0    131156   0% 
/lib/init/rw udev  131156      20    131136   1% 
/dev  tmpfs        131156       0    131156   0% 
/dev/shm none      131156       0    131156   0% 
/dev/shm overflow    1024       0      1024   0% 
/tmp
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying df command output:

Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              9805144   9308424         0 100% /
tmpfs                   131156         0    131156   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                    131156        20    131136   1% /dev
tmpfs                   131156         0    131156   0% /dev/shm
none                    131156         0    131156   0% /dev/shm
overflow                  1024         0      1024   0% /tmp

Comment: Yup, looks like your drive is full.  100% use is bad.

Comment: That means i have to clean up unnecessary files from my server or increase disk space.

Comment: Yes, but you should start with cleaning up disk space ASAP.  If your system is full, then lots of things are broken or not working.  It is an unsafe situation.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the partition where your mysqld is or your data-files are located is full. What is the output of a `df` command (disc-free)?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying .Output of df shows:

Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1              9805144   9308424         0 100% /
tmpfs                   131156         0    131156   0% /lib/init/rw
udev                    131156        20    131136   1% /dev
tmpfs                   131156         0    131156   0% /dev/shm
none                    131156         0    131156   0% /dev/shm
overflow                  1024         0      1024   0% /tmp